# Using ExternalInterface on Chrome Extensions background page possible?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, externalinterface

Using ExternalInterface between SWF embed on background.html and background.html possible?

When creationComplete, ExternalInterface.call("alert", "test") is called, but nothing happens.

When background.html open as file, it works.

SWF and bacground.html are in the same directory.

SWF add in Global Security Panel and flash.system.Security.allowDomain("*");

Google Chrome is latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a function for the externalinterface to call.

Try:

```
ExternalInterface.call("function setLocation() {alert("Hello!");}");
```

or make a js function on your background.html that does the rest of the job for you.

Comment: What about Flash Player?
If you have Pepper Flash it can be the source of the problem.